# Facebook authentication using Facebook C# SDK in MVC

Tags: authentication, facebook-c#-sdk

Are there any good tutorials for beginners for a simple fb log in and log out in MVC? I have tried some tutorials and none of them have worked fully for me.

I would like a tutorial like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?aid=206707&av=328595) but using Facebook C# SDK and also the tutorial doesn't run for me. After some debugging in _LogOnPartial.cshtml the "response.session" is null after a user has logged in.

Comment: you will need to be a bit more precise on type of fb authentication? do you mean a canvas/tabs app. or do you want to use oauth dialog/fb js sdk or it doesn't matter

Comment: doesn't matter which one it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ASP.NET MVC3 canvas app, you can check out https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-canvas-aspnet-sample <strike>https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-canvas-mvc</strike>

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good one

http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20an%20ASP.NET%20MVC%203%20Website%20%28With%20Javascript%20SDK%29&referringTitle=Getting%20Started

Comment: I end up with an infinite redirect loop for that one just like many people in the comments :(

Comment: Then debug it and make it work for you.  It's probably just a url is out of place in the app config.

Comment: I am a beginner it will take me hours

Comment: Welcome to programming.  If it was easy, then everyone would be doing it and our high salaries would drop like a rock!  :)  Happy coding!

Comment: lol true, but surely there must be a tutorial that works straight away?

Comment: No, there is no simple "plz, send me teh codez" solution to this one.  I would suggest taking your time with it, get it figured out, and write your own blog article on it. Then post a link to that article here as an answer (and wait the 12 hours and accept it).  That way it does get fully documented.